# Multiple INNER JOINs in the same table

Tags: mysql, join

So I have these 2 tables:

Objects (idObjects, obj_name)
Relations (idRelations, rel_name, dom_idObjects, cdom_idObjects)

dom and cdom are FK's to the Objects table. They represent a relationship of existing objects.

I am trying to write a query that returns every relation within a certain depht, along with the corresponding object names. So for example if I want every relation within a depht of 1 (a simple relation between 2 objects), I managed to get this to work:

```
SELECT A.rel_name
    ,C1.obj_name AS object1_name
    ,C2.obj_name AS object2_name
FROM relations AS A
INNER JOIN Objects AS C1 ON A.dom_idObjects = C1.idObjects
INNER JOIN Objects AS C2 ON A.cdom_idObjects = C2.idObjects
```

However, when trying to extend this to a depht of 2 or higher I'm not getting any results (and according to my DB there should be several):

```
SELECT A.rel_name
    ,C1.obj_name AS object1_name
    ,C2.obj_name AS object2_name
    ,C3.obj_name AS object3_name
    ,C4.obj_name AS object4_name
FROM relations AS A
INNER JOIN Objects AS C1 ON A.dom_idObjects = C1.idObjects
INNER JOIN Objects AS C2 ON A.cdom_idObjects = C2.idObjects
INNER JOIN Objects AS C3 ON A.dom_idObjects = C2.idObjects
    AND A.cdom_idObjects = C3.idObjects
INNER JOIN Objects AS C4 ON A.dom_idObjects = C3.idObjects
    AND A.cdom_idObjects = C4.idObjects
```

I guess I'm missing something. What gives?

Comment: Can you share some sample data and the result you're trying to get?

Comment: Did you tried to execute this query in PhpMyAdmin? What is the output?

Comment: I did. The output is simply empty. I have lots of relations with a depht of 4 or higher but they aren't showing up in the results. There must be something wrong with the query.